# Pagination bullets move to the left on route change, when using vue-transition

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, swiper.js

I use Vue 3 and swiper.js. Pagination bullets move to the left on route change (when the component is unmounted). Looks like the styling for bullets and the active button disappear as well. I have a reproduction, didn't care about styling much, but it's enough to show the issue. Try switching between router-links on the nav panel and you'll notice the bug. You can only notice it when using vue-transition, because there is a delay and you are able to see it.

Reproduction link:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-c5x8vm?file=src%2FApp.vue,src%2Fmain.js

I'm looking for possible solution.

Comment: @isherwood where exactly do you see me tagging a title?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77997503/revisions

Comment: [ask] also explains that you need to show some code _here_ , not just at another site.

Comment: @isherwood Thanks. But I think showing some code here wouldn't make much sense, since I don't know where exactly the issue comes from. The reproduction though shows a full picture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding this to `style.css` seems to fix the bullets flying during transition:

```css
.swiper-pagination {
  width: 100%;
}

.swiper-pagination-bullet {
  margin: 0 0.25rem 0.5rem;
}
```

[See it here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-f1h38s?file=src%2Fstyle.css).

Comment: Yes, you did it! Thanks. How did you came to this solution? I couldn't find anything like this in the official documentation. Btw, do you know if there's a similar solution for vertical spacing? In my project (not demo that I showed), the buttons also collapse vertically, when going to another route. Looks like adding `margin-top: 29px;` to `swiper-pagination-bullet` fixes it, but I adjusted it pixel by pixel, I don’t know why it works. Maybe you have a more correct solution?

Video:
https://gemoo.com/tools/upload-video/share/617172468339261440?codeId=M0BJ39B98VyYY&card=617172464899932160

Comment: I came to the solution by inspecting current styles and playing with values. But I do know CSS (what each property does). Let's call it old school.